# TypeError: node.ownerDocument is null when using xpath in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, xpath, geckodriver

I have following HTML I want to crawl in Firefox using selenium. I want to get the value of the attribute "title" (= information I want to extract) as well as its text (=more information I want to extract). The element is located inside an iframe.

```
<tr id="id1f7" class="new" data-oao-mailid="tmai16837d54b5315319" data-folderid="tfol11c18fac000026ec">
<td class="slct first">
<span class="form-input form-input-type-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" id="id1f8" name="maillist:rowsCheckGroup" value="check0"/>
</span>
</td>
<td class="mark">
<a class="mail-read-mark marked" data-oao-hover="toggleRead" title="Als gelesen markieren" data-title-read="Als gelesen markieren" data-title-unread="Als ungelesen markieren">
<svg class="mail-read-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#status-unread_24"></use>
</svg>
</a>
</td>
<td class="name" title="information I need to extract;">
more information I need to extract

</td>
<td class="text">
</td>
<td class="date">10:48 Uhr</td>
<td class="size" id="id1f9">63,17 KB</td>
</tr>
```

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='app-contents-wrapper']//iframe")[4]
    driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
    time.sleep(3)
    emails = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains('@data-oao-mailid',tmail) and ./td[@class='name']]")
        
    for w in emails:
        print(w.find_element_by_xpath(".//@title"))
```

However, when I execute the loop I keep getting the error "TypeError: node.ownerDocument is null". This is strange, since when I print out the emails-element,

```
for w in emails:
        print(w)
```

I get results which look like this:

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="ad91d2a0-ed8f-8f44-9646-dad80647b266", element="243d171e-ad4c-d94b-bf8f-698daa971e0c")>
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="ad91d2a0-ed8f-8f44-9646-dad80647b266", element="040e26db-ecb1-a24c-af95-09f91d182e3c")>
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="ad91d2a0-ed8f-8f44-9646-dad80647b266", element="938c8595-e753-9141-926a-71d3fd81963d")>
```

So the code I use to select the "emails"-elements seems to work. However, when I try to iterate through those elements and get the "title"-attribute, it seems like they can't be selected by my xpath-selector.

Comment: `iframe = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='app-contents-wrapper']//iframe")[4]` I believe here you have to use `driver.find_element_by_xpath`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for w in emails:
    w.get_attribute("title")
```

this will print

```
information I need to extract;
```